# php:8.1-fpm-alpine: how to install openssl, pdo_mysql, mbstring and mcrypt

Tags: php, docker, alpine-linux

I'm trying to upgrade an Alpine image from PHP 7.4 to PHP 8.1.

This is the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm-alpine
RUN apk update && \
    apk add bash build-base gcc wget git autoconf libmcrypt-dev \
    g++ make openssl-dev \
    php8-openssl \
    php8-pdo_mysql \
    php8-mbstring \
    php8-mcrypt
```

The errors I get are those:

```
#7 3.780   php8-mbstring (no such package):
#7 3.780 ERROR: unable to select packages:
#7 3.867     required by: world[php8-mbstring]
#7 3.867   php8-mcrypt (no such package):
#7 3.867     required by: world[php8-mcrypt]
#7 3.867   php8-openssl (no such package):
#7 3.867     required by: world[php8-openssl]
#7 3.867   php8-pdo_mysql (no such package):
#7 3.867     required by: world[php8-pdo_mysql]
```

How can install these extensions?

I also tried to add `main` and `community` repos, but without success:

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm-alpine

RUN echo http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main >> /etc/apk/repositories
RUN echo http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community/ >> /etc/apk/repositories

RUN apk update && \
    apk add bash build-base gcc wget git autoconf libmcrypt-dev \
...
```

Comment: not sure how alpine distro does things but i generally have to do this `php8.1-mbstring` etc etc

Comment: You can use `RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) pdo_mysql`

Comment: [mcrypt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mcrypt.php) had been abandoned for years and it was removed in PHP/7.2. There's no way to use it in PHP/8.1, but you shouldn't have been able to use it in PHP/7.4 either  Were you using a PECL release?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, thank you for your clarification... The repo was on PHP7.2, so this is the reason why it used `mcrypt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by elburro1887, there is no package `php81-mcrypt` in the list of packages available for Alpine.

The reason was explained by Álvaro González in the comments to my question

> [mcrypt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mcrypt.php) had been abandoned for years and it was removed in PHP/7.2. There's no way to use it in PHP/8.1.

So, I ended up using PECl in the meantime (I think the library should be removed and substituted with something else) and this is the resulting working `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm-alpine
ARG xdebug_enabled=false

RUN echo http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main >> /etc/apk/repositories
RUN echo http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community/ >> /etc/apk/repositories

# installing required extensions
RUN apk update && \
    apk add bash build-base gcc wget git autoconf libmcrypt-dev libzip-dev zip \
    g++ make openssl-dev \
    php81-openssl \
    php81-pdo_mysql \
    php81-mbstring

RUN pecl install mcrypt && \
    docker-php-ext-enable mcrypt

...
```

Thank you to all of you for the support!

Answer (score 2):

The Alpine packages for PHP 8.1 look like "`php81-xxx`".

Here you can see a list of the available packages for Alpine:

- https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?page=1&branch=edge&name=%2Aphp81%2A&arch=x86_64

It seems there is no package called `php81-mcrypt`. There is a package called `php81-pecl-mcrypt`, but I'm not sure if it's the one you want.

So removing `mcrypt`, this would be a working Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm-alpine
RUN apk update && \
    apk add bash build-base gcc wget git autoconf libmcrypt-dev \
    g++ make openssl-dev \
    php81-openssl \
    php81-pdo_mysql \
    php81-mbstring
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the accepted answers, these are some alternatives:

- Libsodium - A PHP extension
- If you can't use Libsodium, use defuse/php-encryption - Straight PHP code
- If you can't use Libsodium or defuse/php-encryption, use OpenSSL - A lot of servers will already have this installed.